# Pros & cons of the outlined ways to prevent <button> element from submitting its enclosing form

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have a `<button>` element that I want its click to trigger an AJAX POST of a form. If I put the `<button>` element inside of the form, it would respond to clicks with a default behaviour of submitting the form (non-ajax). To prevent this default behaviour of `<button>` element within a form, I can do either of the followings:

1. assign `type="button"` to the `<button>` element
2. call e.preventDefault() in the `click` event handler (ie. using jQuery)
3. move the button to the outside of the form

What are the pros & cons of each approach?

Note: There are uncountable SO posts or materials found on the Internet that talk about HOW to prevent `<button>` element from submitting its enclosing form but none of them talk about WHY. And this is a WHY question.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the second approach:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // AJAX stuff
});
```

The other two approaches make the form unusable for browsers without JavaScript. Buttons that don't do anything will frustrate users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if the assumption is that I don't need to care about users without JavaScript. Would you have a different answer?

Comment: @tamakisquare: Why would you go out of your way to break your forms? The second way is still the only viable option.